# NASM eax, ebx, ecx, edx Divde

Tags: assembly, nasm, division, multiplication, addition

I am working with NASM on 32-bit Ubuntu and I am having difficult time dividing two registers.

Heres my expression shown in C:

```
int A, B, C, D, E, F, Z ;

A = 10;
B = 12 ;
C = A + B ;
D = 3 ;
E = 6 ; 
F = C – D ;

Z = ((A + B * C) / (D – E * F)) + 1 ;
```

My code looks like this:

```
mov eax, dword [B]
mov ebx, dword[C]
mul ebx ; result should be B * C?
add eax, dword [A]
mov eax
```

Result equals 274, as it should, but how do I preserve this value in order to use PEMDAS and solve the other half of the equation separately and then divide? My eax register holding 274 (I think) keeps being overwritten.

Any help thanks?

Comment: You could (1) push it onto the stack (`push eax`) and pop it back off later when you need it (`pop xxx`), (2) declare a dword memory location (say, `temp`) and save it there: `mov temp, eax`, or (3) save it into another unused register, like `mov ecx, eax`.

Comment: You need show your entire code, including the part where EAX is getting overwritten.

Comment: A fourth option would be to write back the evaluated subexpressions to already used variables: D = (D - E * F); A = A + B * C; Z = D/A + 1; Please also notice that `mul xxx` will produce the upper half of the product in `edx`, such as `div xxx` will assume the upper 32 bits of the nominator in edx as well.